# How to get multiple value in Checkbox list (Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I'm able to get Single value from checkbox list for e.g this `query="select * from product where brand="Samsung""`. The samsung Value coming from checkbox list but when I want to pass multiple value 
like this `query="select * from product WHERE Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20" 
How to get "10" and "20"`. from checkbox list

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `Items` collection like this:-

```
foreach (ListItem item in yourCheckBoxListId.Items)
{
     if (item.Selected)
              sb.Append(item.Value);
}
```

Here, `sb` is a `StringBuilder` object, you can store it the way you want, you can use `Text` property to fetch the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
for (int i=0; i<checkboxlistID.Items.Count; i++)
       {
            if (checkboxlistID.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                Message.Text += checkboxlistID.Items[i].Text + "<br />";
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function that takes a CheckBoxList as a parameter and the DB column name and returns the "Where" clause that you can append to your SQL:

```
Public Function GetCheckBoxClause(ByRef a_Listbox As CheckBoxList, ByVal as_ColumnID As String) As String
    Dim ls_Clause As String = String.Empty, ls_Item As String
    Dim li_Count As Integer = 0

    ' Loop thru checkboxes and find selected items
    For li_loop = 0 To a_Listbox.Items.Count - 1
        ls_Item = a_Listbox.Items(li_loop).Value
        If Not IsNumeric(ls_Item) Then ls_Item = "'" & ls_Item & "'"
        If a_Listbox.Items(li_loop).Selected Then
            li_Count += 1
            ls_Clause += ls_Item & ","
        End If
    Next

    ' Finalize
    If li_Count < a_Listbox.Items.Count Then
        If li_Count > 0 Then
            ls_Clause = ls_Clause.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
            If ls_Clause.Contains(",") Then ls_Clause = as_ColumnID & " In (" & ls_Data & ")" Else ls_Clause = as_ColumnID & "=" & ls_Data
        Else
            ls_Clause = "0=1"  ' No item is selected, so SQL is forced to return no rows
        End If
    Else
        ls_Clause = String.Empty   ' All are selected, so nothing to filter
    End If

    Return ls_Clause
End Function
```

If all items in the checkbox list are selected, then it returns an empty string (i.e. nothing to filter in SQL). If nothing is selected in the CheckboxList then it returns "0=1" which will always evaluate to false thereby returning no rows in your SQL.

If you want you can change "0=1" to empty string if you want that not selecting any items is the same as selecting all items.

Code is in VB.Net... Please convert to C# if needed.